# silently transfer keyPressEvent to one child , and make it focus?

Tags: qt, focus, setfocus, qt4.7, qlineedit

When user types in a `QWidget` based window, I wanted a `QLineEdit` to process
all input keys,
so I tried the following two solution in `keyPressEvent()` of that `QWidget`:

A.

```
void Window::keyPressEvent (QKeyEvent *e)
{
   switch (e->key())
   {
     // handle other short cuts
     default:
       QApplication::sendEvent (lineEdit , e);
       break;
   }
}
```

Well, this sometimes crashes the whole interface, especially when I `resize window`.

B.

```
void Window::keyPressEvent (QKeyEvent *e)
{
   switch (e->key())
   {
     // handle other short cuts
     default:

     if ( ! lineEdit.hasFocus () )
     {
        lineEdit.setFocus ();
        lineEdit.setText (e->key()); 
        // i wanted to push the first key input to that QLineEdit , but how ?
        // or i'll miss it
     }
     break;
   }
}
```

Also I'm thinking about giving `lineEdit` focus all the time, but I can't do that as other events needed to be handled by the main UI.

#### Update

It won't crash when I filter key inputs, but why ?

```
 default:
        if ( e->key() == Qt::Key_Backspace || e->key() == Qt::Key_Delete ||
                (e->key() >= Qt::Key_A && e->key() <= Qt::Key_Z )
                )
            QApplication::sendEvent(filter , e);
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are running into a crash because you are using sendEvent to send an event object that you don't have control over.

I don't think the Qt event system expects you to grab its events and throw them in other directions, and it's likely that the event object is getting destroyed before the line edit expects.  In the case where you're filtering out input keys, it's probably not crashing because the line edit doesn't care about those kinds of key strokes and isn't using the event object as much as it would otherwise.

If you really want to use the `sendEvent()` functionality, then I would suggest you create your own QKeyEvent on the stack and pass it to the `sendEvent()` function (as demonstrated [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qcoreapplication.html#sendEvent)), or you can just do something like this:

```
lineEdit.setText( lineEdit.text() + event->text() );
```

Comment: QCoreApplication::sendEvent() happens immediately and the doc states that the pointer is not deleted. So you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing it would be to use `QKeyEvent::text` instead of `QKeyEvent::key` and you should be OK. You might also try to create a copy of `QKeyEvent` and pass it to your `QLineEdit`. Thos are rather hacks than solutions though. If you need shortcuts in main window while `QLineEdit` has focus (assuming it is in this window) you can use `QShortcut` with `Qt::WidgetWithChildrenShortcut` context - this way you can keep your `LineEdit` active at all times.

Answer (score 0):

When a widget does not handle an event, it forwards it to its parent. So using sendEvent() to forward to a child is dangerous, as it can make a recursion.